# iPhone/PHP: Caching XML results

Tags: php, iphone, ios, xml

Well, my problem is quite strange, because it really doesn't make sense.

1)I have a PHP script that brings a XML with some information stored in my MySQL database;

2)When I use this script (or any other) for the first time it brings me the all the information updated (all registries inserted 'til that moment);

3)When I use this script (or any other) again, no matter how many new registries i have in my database, it brings me only the registries that we're brought the first time I used the script;

*I have tested this script on my browser, it works fine, always bringing the most updated state of the database.

What can I do?
Thx.

**EDIT:**

1) How I call the XML parser:

```
NSString *strURL = @"localhost/scripts/bringmethexml-x5.php";
NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];

XMLProcessor *processor = [[XMLProcessor alloc]initProcessor];
[processor syncProcessorWithData:dataURL];
NSMutableArray *a = processor.xmlObjects;
```

2) My PHP script:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/xml");
    echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"LATIN-1\"?>";
    echo "<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC \"-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN\" \"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd\">";
    echo "<plist version=\"1.0\">";

    function getXML($sql="SELECT user FROM database.Posts"){

        $conn   = mysql_connect ("localhost", "user", "password");
        $db     = mysql_select_db("database");
        $result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
        $column = "";
        echo "<array>";

        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $column .= "<dict>";
            foreach ($row as $key => $value){
                $column .= "<key>$key</key>";
                $column .= "<string>$value</string>";
            }
            $column .= "</dict>";
        }

        echo $column;
        echo "</array>";
        echo "</plist>";
    }       
    getXML("SELECT user as USER, msg as MESSAGE, hashtag_1 as ST1, hashtag_2 as ST2, hashtag_3 as ST3, hashtag_4 as ST4, hashtag_5 as ST5, date as DATEPOSTED, coordinate_lat as COORLAT, coordinate_lon as COORLON FROM database.Posts;");
    mysql_close();
?>
```

3) How my the XML gets out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="LATIN-1"?><!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <array>
    <dict>
        <key>(key || nome da fileira do db)</key>
            <string>(valor||object)</string>
        <key>(key || nome da fileira do db)</key>
            <string>(valor||object)</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>(key || nome da fileira do db)</key>
            <string>(valor||object)</string>
        <key>(key || nome da fileira do db)</key>
            <string>(valor||object)</string>
    </dict>
    </array>
</plist>
```

4) XMLProcessor is a parser I made, it gets the NSData from the NSURL and then turns it in to a string and i parse it to fit it in a NSMutableDictionary, here's a link for the class:

http://www66.zippyshare.com/v/7711833/file.html

Comment: I ***wish*** I could cash XML. I'd be rich! `<xml><cashamount><units>USD</units><amount>50000000000000</amount></xml>` (I think the word you're looking for is cache.)

Comment: Can you show us the code where you are making the request to get the XML?

Comment: just did, get a look, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy, if slightly hacky way of fixing this is to add a random variable to the url that you don't really use for anything.

for example http://www.yourwebsite.com/somestuff.xml?random=343453

becasue the url is different each time, it will not use the cache.

you can also do it by adding an anchor: http://www.yourwebsite.com/somestuff.xml#623764527

Here's a function to automate it, just apply it to your nsstring URLS

```
yourURL = [self getUniqueURL:yourURL];


-(NSString*)getUniqueURL:(NSString*)originalURL
{

    NSInteger random = (arc4random() % 100000000) + 1;

    NSString* uniqueURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@#%d",originalURL,random];

    return uniqueURL;

}
```

Comment: i just didn't use it as an ancor, i made a $_REQUEST in the PHP and send the number to a variable (: